# Find the $n^{th}$ term and the sum to $n$ terms of the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

Find the $n^{th}$ term and the sum to  $n$ terms of the series.
$$5+7+13+31+85+.....$$

I couldn't get much idea regarding this. Just an observation that the difference between the term and preceding term forms a GP with a common ratio of $3$. How do I proceed further?

Comment: Okay so you have determined that the difference between the terms is always multiplied by three. I would suggest you write down the equation and see what you can do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n=5+7+3+31+85+....$

Now
$$S_n=5+7+3+31+85+....+T_{n-1}+T_n$$
$$\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }(-)S_n=\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }5+7+3+31+....+T_{n-2}+T_{n-1}+T_n$$
$$\\\rule{13cm}{1pt}$$
$$\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }0=\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }5+[2+6+18+54+....+(T_n-T_{n-1})]-T_n$$
Now,$$T_n=5+[2+6+18+54+....+(T_n-T_{n-1})]-T_n$$
$$=5+\frac{2(3^{n-1}-1)}{3-1}$$
$$=5+3^{n-1}-1$$
$$=4+3^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using already mentioned properties the answer is:
$$
a_n=4+3^{n-1},\quad S_n=4n+\frac{3^n-1}{2}.
$$

Comment: how did you get that? Calculations?

Comment: I think it's relatively easy to just guess the correct formula. If you subtract $4$ from each term, you can easily see the geometric series.

Comment: It is just mathematical expression of the fact that $a_{n+1}−a_n=2⋅3^{n-1}=3^n-3^{n-1}$. It remains only to find suitable constant term common for all $a_n$.